# Logstash extract data from different types of messages

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Below are 3 examples of the type of log I am getting from our automation platform.  I am looking to extract customOptions section.  The challenge i am running into is the custom options section could be many of them.  I think what I need to do is split out the custom options array and then dissect that.  I have tried logstash dissect, grok, and mutate and struggling to get that data out.

```
2020-12-09_18:06:30.58027 executing local task [refId:3122, lockTimeout:330000, lockTtl:300000, jobType:jobTemplateExecute, lockId:job.execute.3122, jobTemplateId:3122, jobDate:1607537190133, userId:1897, customConfig:{"AnsibleRequestedUser":"testing1","AnsibleRequestedUserPassword":"VMware321!"}, jobTemplateExecutionId:5677, customInputs:[customOptions:[AnsibleRequestedUser:testing1, AnsibleRequestedUserPassword:VMware321!]], processConfig:[accountId:947, status:executing, username:user1, userId:1897, userDisplayName:user1 user1, refType:jobTemplate, refId:3122, timerCategory:TEST: 0.  Enterprise Create User, timerSubCategory:3122, description: Enterprise Create User], processMap:[success:true, refType:jobTemplate, refId:3122, subType:null, subId:null, process: : 25172, timerCategory:TEST: 0. OpenManage Enterprise Create User, timerSubCategory:3122, zoneId:null, processId:25172], taskConfig:[:],:@45eb737f]



2020-12-09_15:33:43.21913 executing local task [refId:3117, lockTimeout:330000, lockTtl:300000, jobType:jobTemplateExecute, lockId:job.execute.3117, jobTemplateId:3117, jobDate:1607528023018, userId:320, customConfig:null, jobTemplateExecutionId:5667, customInputs:[customOptions:[AnsibleIdentPoolDesc:asdf123, AnsibleIdentPoolCount:50, TrackingUseCase:Customer Demo/Training, AnsiblePoolName:asdf123]], processConfig:[accountId:2, status:executing, username:user@company.com, userId:320, userDisplayName:user, refType:jobTemplate, refId:3117, timerCategory:TEST: 2.  Enterprise - Create Identity Pool, timerSubCategory:3117, description:TEST: 2. Enterprise - Create Identity Pool], processMap:[success:true, refType:jobTemplate, refId:3117, subType:null, subId:null, process: : 25147, timerCategory:TEST: 2. Enterprise - Create Identity Pool, timerSubCategory:3117, zoneId:null, processId:25147], taskConfig:[:], :@21ff5f47]



2020-12-09_15:30:53.83030 executing local task [refId:3112, lockTimeout:330000, lockTtl:300000, jobType:jobTemplateExecute, lockId:job.execute.3112, jobTemplateId:3112, jobDate:1607527853230, userId:320, customConfig:null, jobTemplateExecutionId:5662, customInputs:[customOptions:[ReferenceServer:10629, ReferenceServerTemplateName:asdfasdf, TrackingUseCase:Internal Testing/Training, ReferenceServerTemplateDescription:asdfasdf]], processConfig:[accountId:2, status:executing, username:user@company.com, userId:320, userDisplayName:user, refType:jobTemplate, refId:3112, timerCategory:TEST: 1. Enterprise - Create Template From Reference Device, timerSubCategory:3112, description:TEST: 1. Enterprise - Create Template From Reference Device], processMap:[success:true, refType:jobTemplate, refId:3112, subType:null, subId:null, process: : 25142, timerCategory:TEST: 1. Enterprise - Create Template From Reference Device, timerSubCategory:3112, zoneId:null, processId:25142], taskConfig:[:],:@29ac1e41]
```

The data need to take the following from the messages above.

Message 1:

> [customOptions:[AnsibleRequestedUser:testing1,
> AnsibleRequestedUserPassword:VMware321!]] I would like those to be in
> a new field.  username:user1 need to have that in a field.
> timerCategory:TEST: 0.  Enterprise Create User need to have this in a
> field.

The rest of the data can stay in the originally field message.

Message 2:

> [customOptions:[AnsibleIdentPoolDesc:asdf123,
> AnsibleIdentPoolCount:50, TrackingUseCase:Customer Demo/Training,
> AnsiblePoolName:asdf123]] - I need these separated into different
> fields.  username:user@company.com needs to be a field.
> timerCategory:TEST: 2.  Enterprise - Create Identity Pool, - I need in
> a field.

Message 3:

> [customOptions:[ReferenceServer:10629,
> ReferenceServerTemplateName:asdfasdf, TrackingUseCase:Internal
> Testing/Training, ReferenceServerTemplateDescription:asdfasdf]], - I
> need these separated into separate fields.  username:user@company.com
>
> - needs to be a field.  timerCategory:TEST: 1. Enterprise - Create Template From Reference Device - needs to be a field.

Now keeping in mind that the timer category will constantly change depending on what the logs spits out but should remain the same format as above.
Custom options will be constantly changing - meaning depending on what automation kicks off will determine more custom options but again the format above should stay the same.
The user name could be email or generic.

Here are some of the log stash filters I have tried with some success but not to handle the changing nature of the log message.

```
# Testing a new method to get information from the logs. 
#if "executing local task" in [message] and "beats" in [tags]{
#   dissect {
#       mapping => {
#           "message" => "%{date} %{?skip1} %{?skip2} %{?skip3} %{?refid} %{?lockTimeout} %{?lockTtl} %{?jobtemplate} %{?jobType} %{?jobTemplateId} %{?jobDate} %{?userId} %{?jobTemplateExecutionId} %{?jobTemplateExecutionId1} customInputs:[customOptions:[%{?RequestedPassword}:%{?RequestedPassword} %{?TrackingUseCase1}:%{TrackingUseCase}, %{?RequestedUser}, %{?processConfig}, %{?status}, username:%{username}, %{?userId}, %{?userDisplayName}, %{?refType}, %{?refID}, %{?timerCategory}:%{TaskName}, %{?timeCat}, %{?description}, %{?extra}"
#       }
#   }
#}
# Testing Grok Filters instead.  
if "executing local task" in [messages] and "beats" in [tags]{
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM2:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day}_%{TIME:time}%{SPACE}%{CISCO_REASON}%{SYSLOG5424PRINTASCII}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE}%{SPACE}%{PROG}%{SPACE}%{PROG}%{SPACE}%{PROG}%{SPACE}%{PROG}%{SPACE}%{PROG}%{SPACE}%{PROG}%{SPACE}%{PROG}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOGPROG}%{SYSLOG5424SD:testing3}%{NOTSPACE}%{SPACE}%{PROG}%{SYSLOG5424SD:testing2}%{NOTSPACE}%{SPACE}%{PROG}%{SYSLOG5424SD:testing}%{GREEDYDATA}}"
        }
    }   
}
```

I think grok is what I need to use but not familiar with how to split / add fields to meet the needs above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend against trying to do everything in a single filter, especially a single grok pattern. I would start by using dissect to strip off the timestamp. I save it in the [@metadata] field so that it is accessible in the logstash pipeline, but does not get processed by the output.

```
    dissect { mapping => { "message" => "%{[@metadata][timestamp]} %{} [%{[@metadata][restOfline]}" } }
    date { match => [ "[@metadata][timestamp]", "YYYY-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSSSS" ] }
```

Next I would break up the restOfLine using grok patterns. If you only need fields from processConfig then that is the only grok pattern you need. I provide the others as an example of how to pull multiple patterns out of one message.

```
    grok {
        break_on_match => false
        match => {
            "[@metadata][restOfline]" => [
                "customOptions:\[(?<[@metadata][customOptions]>[^\]]+)",
                "processConfig:\[(?<[@metadata][processConfig]>[^\]]+)",
                "processMap:\[(?<[@metadata][processMap]>[^\]]+)"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Now we can parse [@metadata][processConfig], which is a key/value string. Again we save the parsed values in [@metadata] and just copy the ones we want.

```
    kv {
        source => "[@metadata][processConfig]"
        target => "[@metadata][processConfigValues]"
        field_split_pattern => ", "
        value_split => ":"
        add_field => {
            "username" => "%{[@metadata][processConfigValues][username]}"
            "timeCategory" => "%{[@metadata][processConfigValues][timerCategory]}"
         }
    }
```

This results in events with fields like

```
    "username" => "user@company.com",
"timeCategory" => "TEST: 2.  Enterprise - Create Identity Pool"
```

Comment: taking the data set that you provided didn't provide any results.  its almost like it by passed the filter all together.  if "executing local task" in [messages] and "beats_morpheus" in [tags] - this is the start of the filter section you have listed above.  I broke them down as you had them.

Comment: the logstash service starts so the syntax appears to be correct and it continues to run.  i sent 3 new logs to it and netted no new fields created.

Comment: I think i found my error - if "executing local task" in [messages] should be message.  Testing again.

Comment: Ok so that fixed the issue - would i do the same thing with customOptions - just setup another KV and add the known fields that i want out fo there like TrackingUseCase if thats one i want to break out of that KV section?

Comment: Yes, just use another kv.

Comment: OK so when i do that i don't get the KV on the custom options.  Following your example with the username and category.  ```  kv {
   source => "[@metadata][customOptions]"
   target => "[@metadata][customOptionsValues]"
   field_split_pattern => ", "
   value_split => ":"
   add_field => {
    "TrackingUseCase" => "%{[@metadata][customOptionsValues][TrackingUseCase]}"
   }
  }```

Comment: If it doesn't find a key value it won't fail right will it just add null?

Comment: trackingUseCase
%{[@metadata][customOptionsValues][TrackingUseCase] --> ok so it looks like it works my own stupidity made an error in syntax. - but it does look like thats what the file will fill out if the data isn't found it just inputs the tracking string.  will have to figure out a way to filter that out later.  Thanks for the help this gets me at least started.

Answer (score 0):

This another response focus on grok (but I'm agree it's bit difficult to maintain in the time, and also to just understand in the present).

1. Extract with correct (and a bit long) grok expression the field *customOptions*
2. Work only on this specific field with another filter (key value) and put in the *customOptionsSplitter* field for example (to avoid to break existing field).

This code is an implementation of this :

```
filter{

    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{DATE:date}_%{TIME:time} %{CISCO_REASON} \[refId\:%{INT:refId}, lockTimeout:%{INT:lockTimeout}, lockTtl:%{INT:lockTtl}, jobType:%{NOTSPACE:jobType}, lockId:%{NOTSPACE:lockId}, jobTemplateId:%{INT:jobTemplateId}, jobDate:%{INT:jobDate}, userId:%{INT:userId}, customConfig:(\{%{GREEDYDATA:customConfig}\}|null), jobTemplateExecutionId:%{INT:jobTemplateExecutionId}, customInputs:\[customOptions:\[%{GREEDYDATA:customOptions}\]\], processConfig:\[%{GREEDYDATA:processConfig}\], processMap:\[%{GREEDYDATA:processMap}\], taskConfig:\[%{GREEDYDATA:taskConfig}\], :%{NOTSPACE:serial}\]"
        }
    }

    kv {
        source => "customOptions"
        target => "customOptionsSplitter"
        field_split_pattern => ", "
        value_split => ":"
    }

}
```